# UITableView duplicating row when reloading tableview after updating datasource and using insertRowsAtIndexPaths?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

TableView consist of 3 sections with each appended to an array for row values , these array are interrelated through a button in the accessory view of each cell,hence when the button is pressed the underlying datasource is changed and table is reloaded, to match the number of rows before and after update following code is used :

```
        int sentCount = [[self sendersList] count];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToMove = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(sentCount - 1) inSection:2];

        [tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathToMove] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
       [tableview endUpdates];
       [tableview reloadData];
```

what I am getting is the duplicate of original row at this new indexpath not the cell that was supposed to be shown by cellForRowAtIndexPath after getting the data from datasource.

I have logged and checked the section in which the row is getting inserted is being called appropriate number of times but the value displayed is duplicate copy of original cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the core problem was that I was using same cell Identifier for all three sections , when they had little bit different cell components, hence compiler was returning the same cell despite having different underlying datasource , to solve I just used a different cell identifier for different sections.